# Button push status property GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab, properties, uibutton, matlab-gui

Is there any possibility to change btn1 value or some sort of it's status/property when it's pushed?

For example:

I've got 2 pushbuttons btn1 and btn2 in my GUI. When I click btn1 the value/flag/status of itself changes autommaticaly to another value(maybe true/1) so i can use it in my code to do some operations.

Is there any option to do it? Except the global values.

I really want to do it programmatically and avoid appdesigner if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have experience using callback functions?

You could try to run this and apply it to your problem.

```
function buttonTest
% create figure
fig = figure;
% create first push button
btn1 = uicontrol(...
    'Parent',fig,...
    'style','pushbutton',...
    'units','normalized',...
    'Position',[0.1 0.15 0.8 0.2],...
    'String','BTN 1',...
    'Callback',@myfunction);
% create second push button
btn2 = uicontrol(...
    'Parent',fig,...
    'style','pushbutton',...
    'units','normalized',...
    'Position',[0.1 0.65 0.8 0.2],...
    'String','BTN 2',...
    'Callback',@myfunction);
% Generate loop to automatically run function behind push buttons
for i = 1:5
   myfunction(btn1)
   pause(1)
   myfunction(btn2)
   pause(1)
end

%% Callback function
function myfunction(source,~)
    % detect source from call and display it.
    if strcmpi(source.String,'BTN 1')
        disp('BTN 1 pushed')
    elseif strcmpi(source.String,'BTN 2')
        disp('BTN 2 pushed')
    end
end
end
```

In stead of showing the button pushed, you should of course run your own scheme.